# Developing layout for various types of mobile resolutions Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I am developing the layout of an application developed using the cord, however you like to know how to develop the various types of resolutions that exist in the mobiles devices, would have some tutorial, book or video talking about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap for responsive UI. So it support in all kinds of devices. You can also use some platforms like **IONIC** which supports native like look. http://ionicframework.com/